# Rcpp cannot convert ‘SEXP {aka SEXPREC*}’ to ‘double’ in initialization

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to duplicate the R vectorised sum in Rcpp

I first try the following trouble-free code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double call(NumericVector x){
  return sum(x);
}
```

Type `call(Time)`

```
> call(Time)
[1] 1919853
```

Then an environment version, also works well,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double call(){
  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  NumericVector Time = env["Time"];
  return sum(Time);
}
```

Type `call()`

```
> call()
[1] 1919853
```

Now I am trying something weird as following,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double call(){
  Environment base("package:base");
  Function sumc = base["sum"];
  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  NumericVector Time = env["Time"];
  double res = sumc(Time);
  return res;
}
```

This time I got a error message:

```
trycpp.cpp:10:25: error: cannot convert ‘SEXP {aka SEXPREC*}’ to ‘double’ in initialization
double res = sumc(Time);
```

Any idea what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call an R function (ie `sumc()` on one of Rcpp's vectors. Do this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double mycall(){
  Environment base("package:base");
  Function sumc = base["sum"];
  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  NumericVector Time = env["Time"];
  double res = sum(Time);
  return res;
}
```

Here `sum()` is the Rcpp sugar function.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk Eddelbuettel, the reason I try the last method is I want to duplicate the following R vectorised summation sum(Time[Time<100]). Any hints on how to do it in Rcpp ?

Comment: Yes, several posts here (including _yesterday_ !!) on how to do indexing.   Thanks for accepting the answer, you can also upvote (click on up-arrow).