# Rcpp: Converting SEXP to float/double

Tags: r, floating-point, type-conversion, double, rcpp

```
SEXP callFunction1(List network, List words, Function testWordContinuity){
  SEXP res = testWordContinuity(network, words);
  return res;
}

for(int i=0; i<(n_epochs); i++){
  NumericVector outputMatchTracker = history["output.match.tracker"];
  outputMatchTracker[i] = callFunction1(network, words, testWordContinuity);
}
```

The testWordContinuity function in R calls another function in R that returns a single numeric variable

All I'm doing with res is replacing values in a vector using the for loop. The first line after the beginning of the for loop is assigning outputMatchTracker to a vector of zeros (history["output.match.tracker"]) so I can loop over the zeros.

The error: "Cannot convert 'SEXP' to 'Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}' in assignment" occurs on the last line in the for loop above.

Is there a way to convert res from SEXP to float or double?

I realize a similar question has been asked here:
[Rcpp cannot convert ‘SEXP {aka SEXPREC*}’ to ‘double’ in initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596567/rcpp-cannot-convert-sexp-aka-sexprec-to-double-in-initialization) but that question was solved by using an Rcpp sugar function instead of an R function to avoid converting SEXP into a double.

If there is not a way to convert from SEXP to float or double, is there a common way to get around this problem besides just coding the R function in Rcpp?

Happy to provide more information if necessary,

Thank you.

Edit:

Minimum Reproducible Example:

In Rcpp:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP callFunction(Function func){
  SEXP res = func();
  return(res);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector func1(Function func){
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    NumericVector vect(10);
    vect[i] = callFunction(func);
  }
  return(vect);
}
```

Upon sourcing this code the error specified above will appear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There is a lot of verbiage in your question, but no [_minimal reproducible example_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and as such little we can say in response.   Please edit to provide something minimal yet complete that triggers the error.

Comment: Have you tried the `as<>` operator? @DirkEddelbuettel authored an article that is very thorough for these type of things.  It can be found [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/).

Comment: _Psst_ @JosephWood Dirk has authored many wonderful _Rcpp_ articles; however, I wrote that one :)

Comment: @coatless, I feel like an idiot. That was super careless and unintentional. I'm in the Rcpp Galary on a daily basis and found that article very fast, copied the link, and didn't even bother to look at the author.  I'm very sorry.  I have huge respect for you and promote your work and websites often.

Comment: Seems like you put your results in a `NumericVector`, so why not always using `double` instead of `SEXP`?

Comment: @JosephWood no worries mate. 'Tis hard to see anything _Rcpp_-related without Dirk. :)

Comment: The as<> operator did the trick. I had tried that before, but apparently with the incorrect syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are supposed to use the `REAL` macro, which returns a pointer to the start of a `double` array. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Attributes for an example.

Comment: Not needed in the Rcpp world. `cppFunction("double plusTwo(double x) { return x + 2.0; }")`.  Ditto for `Rcpp::NumericVector` if you want a vector instead a (C/C++) scalar.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of [Simon Byrne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056159/rcpp-converting-sexp-to-float-double#answer-49056420) - there are 2 ways to achieve this that I am aware of:

1. Remember that scalars in R are actually always vectors with a length of 1. Therefore convert an R `SEXP` object to an RCPP `NumericVector` and use index (square bracket) notation to reference the first element:

```cpp
double callFunction1(List network, List words, Function testWordContinuity){
  SEXP res = testWordContinuity(network, words);
  NumericVector dblVec(res)
  return dblVec[0];
}
```

2. use the `REAL` macro and de-reference the pointer (to the first element). This may well be a micro-optimisation compared to approach 1 (untested), but the bottleneck will almost certainly be the `testWordContinuity` R function. There is also an `asReal` function in the `<Rinternals.h>` C library, but given the `REAL` macro is included in the `<Rcpp.h>` header file, it would seem to add unnecessary complexity to bother including `<Rinternals.h>`.

```cpp
double callFunction1(List network, List words, Function testWordContinuity){
  SEXP res = testWordContinuity(network, words);
  return *REAL(res);
}
```